# Почему не срабатывает код при некоторых значениях пин?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем здравствуйте, я новичок здесь.
Хотелось бы спросить, почему такой код не работает при например `pin = "a234"` или `pin = "-111"`
И как это исправить, заранее спасибо!
Сам код:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
a = len(pin)
if (a == 4 or a == 6 and pin.isdigit()):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Как понять ваше "не работает"?

Comment: при некоторых значениях, например a234 или -111 возвращает не то, что нужно, нужно False, но возвращает True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расставьте скобки. Сейчас проверяется не совсем то, что нужно:

```
if ((a == 4 or a == 6) and pin.isdigit()):
```

Что было: сначала проверялось, равна ли длина pin четырем символам. Т.к. и у `а234` и у `-111` длина равна четыре символа, то условие удовлетворено, и дальнейшие проверки не делались (поскольку `or`). В этом легко убедиться, поменяв местами `a == 4` и `a == 6` в исходном коде. Результат будет отличаться, поскольку первая проверка будет на длину в шесть символов.

Было: pin из четырех символов (любых) ИЛИ (пин из шести символов и только и цифр).

Стало: (pin из 4 или из 6 символов) И только из цифр.